# User cannot create listview

Tags: permissions, administration, list-view

Cannot create a list view!

User can not create a list view on the custom object.
I went to `setup->profile-> edit the profile -> managed public list view [checkbox checked]` but still the user can not create a list view after assigning the permission.
what else do I need to do?

Following permission are assigned:

1. Manage Public List Views
2. Create and Customize List Views

but still see the grayed out in list view

[image]

Comment: so the custom object is a related list to the Account but I can able to create a list view in the Account object but I can not create list view to related list custom object.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about List Views (i.e. the list of records on the Custom Object Tab) or about a Related List (i.e. the list of Custom Object records viewed from the parent Account's tab). From your screen shot, it appears you are trying to modify a Related List.

In order for someone to manage the fields on a related list, that person needs the authorization '`Customize Application`' on their profile. Then the modifications can be done on the parent object's page layout, in this case the Account page layout.

Comment: yes its a related list to the account object but after assigning the `Customize Application` in profile I still see the grayed out area when I try to create a list view

Comment: The modifications can be done on the parent object's page layout, in this case the Account page layout (on Setup). Not on the actual related list on the Account page.